# Grails NumberFormatException or GroovyCastException with fields, that cause it

Tags: validation, exception, grails, try-catch, throw

I'm throwing exceptions in services (especially these validation ones) and try-catch them in controllers. I'm getting data to

in firmController:

```
try{
    def data = request.JSON
    firmService.createAndSave(data)
}
catch(ValidationException exception){
}
```

in firmService:

```
def createAndSave(data){
    firm.year = data.year as BigDecimal
    firm.price = data.price as Float
    firm.employees = data.employees as Integer
    firm.name = data.name
    if(!firm.validate()){
        throw new ValidationException(null, firm.errors)
    }
    firm.save(flush:true)
    firm
}
```

but if I send JSON with invalid data: `{year:"asd", price: "fgh", employees: "3", name: "zxc"}` I got an NumberFormatException. I know, I can catch NumberFormatException (or some kind of my own exception) in controller but how can I get a fields/properties for which it were thrown (and still throw it as an exception)?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of constraints should I add to this type of command object, which will handle f.e. BigDecimal as BigDecimal and String as BigDecimal validation?

Comment: Consider also that I'm sending a JSONObject to service (if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current approach that you are using to initialize your domain object you can't. The NFE is being thrown when grails tries to cast `String` value `asd` as `BigDecimal` (`data.year as BigDecimal`) and it has nothing to do with `ValidationException`.

`JSONObject` class implements `Map` and in grails all Domains have a constructor that accepts a `Map` and can initialize the object using map properties. So instead of binding each property manually you can directly instantiate the object using `new Firm(data)` in `firmService`. In this way you will get a binding exception when grails will try to bind a non decimal value to a `BigDecimal` type field.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!